# CodeMirror extracting code and render HTML not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror

I've been messing around with CodeMirror to provide my textarea with syntax highlighting for HTML, but I also want to be able to click a button to render the HTML code in a separate div.

This is what I have for my functions so far:

```
    <script>
        /*create the CodeMirror editor*/
        var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {lineNumbers: true}); 

        /*Grab the text from the editor and return it*/
        function extractCode() { 
            var text = editor.mirror.getValue();
            return text;
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        /*When the showmeImg image is clicked, grab the code with extractCode and send it to the output div*/
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#showmeImg").click(function(){
                $("#output").html($(extractCode).val());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I'm fairly new to javascript and jquery so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right at all. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason it wasn't working. There's no need for ".val()" at the end of the jquery function, since extractCode already gets the value. Omitting .val() fixes the issue.